# Que signifie « garder mon air » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

J'ai lu dans un texte ce passage :

> J’ai cinq plaies sur mon corps. La plus ouverte est celle des mots. Quand ma bouche s’ouvre, j’ai toutes les peines du monde à garder mon air. Le corps social m’a conseillé de la fermer, …ma bouche.

Que signifie « garder mon air » ?

Answer (score 5):

L'air est ici celui qu'on respire.

Il s'agit d'une expression imagée pour :

> J'ai toutes les peines du monde à **me retenir de parler**.